# Pass data into partial views

Tags: php, zend-framework

In codeigniter I would normally get my data and pass it into the view using $this->load->view('page',$data);
Then manipulate the data as required in the 'page' view.
How do I pass data into my partial views in Zend?

On a similar note I have put this line of code in my main layout view:

```
$this->layout()->content
```

Where is this set and how do you set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All controllers have a `view` property. To set a variable do:

```
$this->view->key = $value;
```

To pass data to a partial view, populate the second parameter to `$this->partial` in your view, like:

```
$this->partial('partial.html', array('message' => 'Hello'));
```

Your partial.html can then print message with echo echo `$this->message`.

As per your last question about `$this->layout()->content` im not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

The Zend Framework documentation has good content on this:

[Views](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.introduction.html)

[Partial helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#partial)

Comment: Hi Alexn, Thanks for your response. With respect to the $this->layout->content, the text I am reading is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.layout.usage.html, I cant see how to set the 'content' variable of the layout object within the controller or how to access it in the view. Whenever I try it crashes with an internal server error. Its me not doing it right, not a problem with the server though.